# android ontouchevent opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch-event

I am using opengl es for my android game. I want to catch the x and y position. I followed a bunch a different tutorial and everything leads to the same result: I cannot get anything out of it. The method isnt even called which I find odd. So, here is my GLSurfaceView Class

```
class OpenGLES10SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    //private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
    public OpenGLES10Renderer mRenderer;
    //static private float mPreviousX;
    //static private float mPreviousY;
    private static float _x;
    private static float _y;

    public OpenGLES10SurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        // set the mRenderer member
        mRenderer = new OpenGLES10Renderer(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        // Render the view only when there is a change
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
            // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
            // interested in events where the touch position changed.

            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                         mRenderer.setX(x);
                                         return true;

            }

    }
    }
```

I cant find what th heck is wrong with this so if you could help that would be IMMENSELY appriciated. If you need toher parts of code, please say so.

Comment: Did you remember to set the OnTouchListener on your View?

Comment: Can you include the part where you set the contentview in your activity? Also, try adding an onTouchEvent() in the activity as well, that should receive the event if none of the views consume it which could help you to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mRenderer.setX(x);
            requestRender();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:         
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:               
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:       
            break;
    }   


    return true;
  }
```

I added other actions in case you need them. Hope that helps.

Comment: Still didnt do anything. I also tried using default:mRenderer.setX(x); but it also didnt work

Comment: Take a look at my edit, you probably forgot to add `requestRender();`

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed. But the thing is that onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) is no even called..

Comment: Well in that case, I would recommend this OpenGL example code. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/OpenGLES.zip